# How to have C# program only store files younger than 7 days in temporary directory

Tags: c#

I have the following class which will put all files from a particular location of the device into a temporary directory:

```
private void GetLogs()
{
try
{
    if (CurrentLogs.DoesExist())
    {
        string tmpLoc = Path.Combine(_TempPath, "CurrentLogs");
        Directory.CreateDirectory(tmpLoc);

        File.WriteAllText(string.Concat(tmpLoc, @"\error.txt"), CurrentLogs.GetLog("logs/error"));
        File.WriteAllText(string.Concat(tmpLoc, @"\debug.txt"), CurrentLogs.GetLog("logs/debug"));
        File.WriteAllText(string.Concat(tmpLoc, @"\debug2.txt"), CurrentLogs.GetLog("logs/debug2"));
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)  {
        var e = ex;
}
}
```

This works well however I'm finding this collects too many files and I need to only collect logs from this location that are not older than 7 days.

I was thinking about using something similar to the following but it doesn't seem to work:

```
private void GetLogs()
{
try
{
    if (CurrentLogs.DoesExist())
    {
        string tmpLoc = Path.Combine(_TempPath, "CurrentLogs");
        Directory.CreateDirectory(tmpLoc);

        DateTime FileAgeLimit = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7);
        DateTime dt = File.GetLastWriteTime(path);

        foreach (var file in CurrentLogs) {
            if (dt < FileAgeLimit {
                File.WriteAllText(string.Concat(tmpLoc, @"\error.txt"), CurrentLogs.GetLog("logs/error"));
                File.WriteAllText(string.Concat(tmpLoc, @"\debug.txt"), CurrentLogs.GetLog("logs/debug"));
                File.WriteAllText(string.Concat(tmpLoc, @"\debug2.txt"), CurrentLogs.GetLog("logs/debug2"));
            }
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)  {
        var e = ex;
    }
}
}
```

Is anyone able to see the error of my ways? :)

Comment: Do `Path.Combine` to create paths, not `String.Concat` (and let it figure out the path separator for you).

Comment: If it´s a large log and you will do some fancy analytics I would persist them with timestamp. small/slow DB should be enough and you can easily get/delete/dashboard/... them.

Comment: Your assignment to `dt` would need to be within the `foreach` loop, if you want to check each file.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work is not informative. If there are errors then provide the error details. But your code is missing a closing parenthesis. You also should not catch an Exception but do nothing with it other than discard it.

Comment: ` if (dt < FileAgeLimit {` syntax error.

Comment: The variable dt needs to be calculated inside your loop, once for each file.

Answer (score 0):

The error of your ways was that you were only checking the date of one of the files.
This should do the trick.

```
            try
            {
            string tmpLoc = Path.Combine(_TempPath, "CurrentLogs");
            Directory.CreateDirectory(tmpLoc);
            DateTime FileAgeLimit = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7);

            foreach (var filePath in Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\data\test"))
            {
                if (File.GetLastWriteTime(filePath) < FileAgeLimit)
                {
                    //
                    //If you make it in here you have a filePath for a file that's older than 7 days
                    //Do your work here
                    //
                }
            }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var e = ex;
            }
```